# PHP Mysqli trigger a query one after other

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to fetch first id from one table and later after all the ids are fetched i am trying to fetch number of all that id's.

My Problem is

- As i want to select the value of first query completion result
- I am unable to trigger second query after the first query is completed both are triggerid at a time

  First Query

  ```
  $query ="SELECT * FROM abc WHERE  xyz='xyz' And Standard='xyz' ";
          $data=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
          $ID = array();
          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
              $ID[] = $row['ID'];


      }
      $IDall = "'" . implode("','", $ID) . "'";
  ```

Second Query

```
        $query="SELECT  mobno FROM euser WHERE UserId IN ($IDall)" ;
                    $data=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
                    $mobiles = array();
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
                        $mobiles[] = $row['MobileNum'];

                    }
                    $mobilesStr = implode(',', $mobiles);


                    echo $mobilesStr;


                }
```

Comment: Do you know `trigger` is a concept in databases?. Do you mean that trigger or are just using it casually?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky , I Mean to say was the second query should wait until first query completion and later second query should fetch the data by using first query's result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT  mobno FROM euser WHERE UserId IN (SELECT ID FROM abc WHERE  xyz='xyz' And Standard='xyz');
```

Comment: How can the `SELECT  mobno FROM euser WHERE` know that it should fetch `MobileNum` by using `ID` according to me the `ID` is not mentioned in the query any where

Comment: error `Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C`

Comment: You cannot select multiple columns for an IN sub query

Comment: SELECT  mobno FROM euser WHERE UserId IN (SELECT ID FROM abc WHERE  xyz='xyz' And Standard='xyz'); my mistake select id instead of select * :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 2 queries. Only 1 is enough

```
SELECT  mobno FROM euser WHERE UserId IN (
  SELECT ID FROM abc ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $query ="SELECT * FROM abc WHERE  xyz='xyz' And Standard='xyz' ";
    $data=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());

    if(mysqli_num_rows($data) > 0) {
       $ID = array();
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
        $ID[] = $row['ID'];
      }
      $IDall = "'" . implode("','", $ID) . "'";

      $query2="SELECT  mobno FROM euser WHERE UserId IN ($IDall)" ;
      $data2=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query2)or die(mysqli_error());
      $mobiles = array();
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data2)){
        $mobiles[] = $row['MobileNum'];
      }
      $mobilesStr = implode(',', $mobiles);
      echo $mobilesStr;
     }
```

In this the second query will execute when the first query has a result.